# CSS: Scrolling Logo Row in pure CSS

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to build a horizontal row of n Logos, that scrolls automatically left and right.
I don't get all logos to show up, what am I missing?
(obviously, the speed is fester than planned and the green background only for visualization):
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/fabcgn/pen/xxWymdY)

```css
.logo-slider-container {
  margin: 0px;
  background: limegreen;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo-slider {
  display: flex;
  animation: scrollHor 5s infinite linear alternate;
}

.logo-slider>img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@keyframes scrollHor {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-slider-container">
  <div class="logo-slider">
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/5953ca02-442e-41e1-89ff-aca1a4ad48ef.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/9f2b6aa9-4f28-49da-997c-d40dd37c92e3.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/557b5422-9c3b-49bd-9837-10ba17b36ebe.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/75cb6df8-f13c-4a53-b204-a0eca47d0c97.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/d1fa74b5-c9ef-486b-a2c6-b5ff973985f6.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/0fc41128-ee5d-477d-8d4d-8b6789762dfa.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/b55c30a9-93c7-4e20-a848-537f5a45b844.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/41fb926d-6ed3-45c1-96fc-b18a46a7575a.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/e616b296-1c1d-4599-ae41-af761f0e090b.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/99d0a342-c525-421e-9416-d2da2510433a.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/d172be64-fdc3-41fc-acdc-e5c336cbeaa8.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/9b7fd7a1-48f0-49e7-b041-b2736c310997.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/41728d40-b08b-47f5-bce0-573738249ba4.svg" />
    <img alt="client logo 2" src="https://d1pnnwteuly8z3.cloudfront.net/images/25535d90-e795-464a-8434-cc304cb2dad8/9b17e24f-1b4e-46d9-96ae-a543d7514244.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Leave out the animation, and just set `margin-left: -100%` as a static value - and you will see that this is not enough to show _all_ logos including the last one, to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you answer. 
Why should I leave the animation out? It's all about the animation.
Especially on smaller screens, when only a few logos show up. 
My goal is to show all logos eventually and scroll left and right continously.

Comment: _"Why should I leave the animation out?"_ - to clearly see where the actual problem lies - this does not move your `.logo-slider` element over to the left _far enough_, to show all of the logos. If it doesn't do that in the "static" version already, then it won't behave better when you "animate" it either.